# Why JSON.parse doesn't work in mongodb find method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, express

Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
Code:

```
collection3.find({username: req.body.accept}).toArray((error, user) => {
            a = JSON.parse(user)
        })
```

Comment: What do you want to do by passing function to `toArray` function?

Comment: Why do you parse an object? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `user` variable is an object. The `JSON.parse` function expects to be passed a string, not an object. If you pass an object, you will get the 'Unexpected token o' error message. You can produce this error message directly by running the following code:

```
JSON.parse({})
```

The working equivalent of the above code is:

```
JSON.parse('{}')
```